# EF 6, multiple navigation properties recommendation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is EF6, code first.  I am fairly new to EF.

I have a class FollowUp.cs (for a CRM):

```
public class FollowUp
{
   public int FollowUpId { get; set; }
   public int? ProspectId { get; set; }        
   public int? CustomerId { get; set; }        
   public int? ContractorId { get; set; }        

   [ForeignKey("ProspectId")]
   public virtual Prospect Prospect { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("ContractorId")]
   public virtual Contractor Contractor { get; set; }
   ...
```

A follow-up record can be for a Customer, Prospect or Contractor (note: these classes are quite different and they do not inherit from a common base class).  I am not thrilled with having three nullable foreign key properties (ProspectId, etc.) - especially since more could be added in the future.

I was thinking of instead only using one foreign key property and a FollowUpEntityType  property to indicate what type of entity the key refers to:

```
public class FollowUp
{
   public int FollowUpId { get; set; }
   public int FollowUpEntityId { get; set; }        // The Id of the Prospect or Customer or Contractor (as indicated by FollowUpEntityType)
   public FollowUpEntityType FollowUpEntityType { get; set; } // An enum (Prospect, Customer, Contractor)

   public virtual Prospect Prospect { get; set; }
   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
   public virtual Contractor Contractor { get; set; }
   ...
```

In the actual DB, EF would still have to create multiple FKs, but I would not have to have multiple in the class.  But with this approach, **is it even possible to make the navigation properties work (without a lot of complexity)?**

It seems to me that the first approach is the most feasible one despite the multiple nullable FK properties, but **I would like to get some feedback / suggestions on how to best handle this scenario.**

Comment: I'd imagine some future nightmare if you followed that (second) approach. I've been in a project that used the first approach with multiple entities and it was not so bad, but this is very opinionated, which is off topic on this site.

Comment: interesting, i do wonder if EF going to support something like polymorphic relationship in Laravel. since, as far as i am aware, there is no way to run from using multiple navigation properties and do `if`s. even EF many-to-many relationship is an abomination..

Comment: Take a lookat TPH. http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy